# Are the results of Word JS API search sorted?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

Can I safely assume [body search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#word-word-body-search-member(1)) results are sorted by order of occurrence in the body?

I.e., will `context.document.body.search("cat");` always return the first occurrence of `cat`, followed by the second, followed by the third, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try to run the following code under the debugger attached:

```
// Link to full sample: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/word/25-paragraph/search.yaml
await Word.run(async (context) => {
  const results = context.document.body.search("Online");
  results.load("length");

  await context.sync();

  // Let's traverse the search results... and highlight...
  for (let i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
    results.items[i].font.highlightColor = "yellow";
  }

  await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for answering. I see that the results appear to be sorted by occurrence. However, as this isn't stated in their API documentation (at least from what I can see), I'm concerned that there are circumstances where this won't be the case. Also, as they haven't officially committed to sorting the results by order of occurrence, I'm concerned someone will later change the search algorithm (perhaps to optimise it) and sacrifice the ordering (maybe because they find a more efficient algorithm which doesn't preserve the order), thus breaking any code that depends on the current order.

Comment: I've never seen non-ordered results.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your insight, Eugene.